# Patterns in Binary Numbers

Tags: c, binary

> Consider an n-bit binary number in the following form:
>
> b<sub>n−1</sub>b<sub>n−2</sub>b<sub>n−3</sub>...b<sub>0</sub>
>
> Each b<sub>i</sub> is a single bit in the n-bit binary number. Each b<sub>i</sub> has one of two possible values: 0 or 1. An example of a 6-bit binary number is: 110011. Inside the computer, integers are represented as binary numbers. For example, the integer 43 can be represented by the 6-bit binary number: 101011. In this part, we will make use of an m-bit binary pattern that is constructed by taking the first m-bits of the repeating sequence 101010. . . . For example, for m equal to 3, the binary pattern is: 101. For m equal to 6, the binary pattern is: 101010. For m equal to 1, the binary pattern is: 1.
>
> Write a C program that reads integers n and m as input, and then prints out all n-bit binary numbers that contain the m-bit pattern. The binary numbers must be printed in ascending order. You are not allow to use strings, arrays or recursion for this question. Any program that uses strings, arrays or recursion will receive a grade of 0. Your program may assume that n will be a natural number less than or equal to 30, and that m will be a natural number less than or equal to n.
>
> A sample output for this program is:
>
> Enter an integer n: (5)
> Enter an integer m: (3)
> 00101
> 01010
> 01011
> 01101
> 10100
> 10101
> 10110
> 10111
> 11010
> 11011
> 11101

I'm a beginner in programming and I've gotten this assignment to do. I understand how the program is going to work but I'm not too sure how to go about it. Can anyone help me out and post a solution to this so I can run through it and see how it works. Thanks

Comment: Homework what do you have so far ?  Cheating gets you no where in life especially when you've scanned the entire ditto onto SO.

Comment: left shift (<<) and or (|) are your friends for solving this.

Comment: You will get much better answers if you post what you have so far. It is unethical to simply ask someone "can you do my homework for me and let me take a look at it." It is fine to ask "here's how far I've gotten, but I'm stuck on this part; can someone help me figure out what's going wrong?"

Answer (score 10):

How to program, a two-step process:

1. Solve the problem yourself.
2. Make the computer do what you did.

You should at least post your "I understand how the problem is going to work" so that you can be guided towards "how to go about it".

---

I'm gonna pretend I don't know C for now.

[J](http://www.jsoftware.com/)

```
f=:4 :'#:(#~([:+./(#.y$1 0)=(2^y)|<.@-:^:(i.x))"0)i.2^x'
```

[Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/)

```
f n m = filter bits [0..1^n-1] where
    p = foldl ((+).(*)2) 0 $ take m $ cycle [1,0]
    bits = elem p . map (`mod` 2^m) . takeWhile (/= 0) . iterate (`div` 2)
```

Comment: I like this because it says so much and so little at the same time.

Comment: -1 for not understanding the problem ;)
"Any program that uses strings, arrays or recursion will receive a grade of 0."

Comment: No strings or recursion used in the code here.  J uses arrays because it's impossible to write anything non-trivial in the language otherwise, and I claim that lists in Haskell are not arrays :)

Comment: Didn't actually downvote you :) I'm glad you're the top answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out what the value of M represents with the repeating sequence. (e.g. 3 = 101)  Chop off the tail end of the number you're testing one step at a time with x/2 or x >> 1 and see if the length of remainder you care about matches.  (test % (1 << m) == 101)

**Edit:** In python...

```
binary = lambda i, c = (lambda i, c: i and (c(i >> 1, c) + str(i & 1)) or ''): c(i, c)
def SilentsHomework(M, N):
 count, base = 0, int(''.join([str([0,1,0][(-1)**x]) for x in xrange(N)]),2)>>(N-M)
 for i in xrange(1,1<<N):
  orig_i_nal = i
  while i:
   if i%(1<<M)==base: count += 1; print binary(orig_i_nal); break
   else: i >>= 1
```

Strings, check.  Arrays, check.  Recursion, nope `:(`

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some clues. Only clues. Because answers for all homeworks would be like a girl in bikini. You have to guess a lot.

To generate the m bit pattern, use a loop starting from 0 to m.

```
for( i = 1; i <= m; i++)
{
    Pattern = ( Pattern * 2 ) + ( i % 2 )
}
```

To generate an n bit number in ascending order, you should write a loop starting from 1 to 2^n.

```
for( i = 1; i < pow( 2, n ); i++ )
```

Next step is to check whether the *`Pattern`* is present in *`i`*. This [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572290/fastest-way-to-scan-for-bit-pattern-in-a-stream-of-bits/1579944#1579944) will help you for that.